# Responsive div with fixed aspect ratio dynamic child div

Tags: html, css

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/0d5gq6yw/) is a JSFiddle. I applied the [padding trick](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_aspect_ratio.asp) which works for horizontal resize. However, it doesn't work for vertical resize. In other words, I want the height of the yellow div to be a fixed percentage, say 15% of the container. But the aspect ratio of the yellow should stay fixed. So if I resize (downsize for instance) vertically, my goal is for the width of the yellow div to decrease as well as the height in order to: 1) maintain the aspect ratio. 2) maintain the percentage width **and** height of the yellow div. Is this possible without JavaScript? I'm fine with any CSS3 if available.

Below is the code as well:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%; 
} 
.container {
 position: relative;
  left: 10%;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  top: 10%;
  background-color: maroon;
}
.content {
  background-color: yellow;
    width: 20%;
    padding-top: 10%;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    left: 40%;
    /* height: 15%; of course this doesn't work */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content"> 
        
  </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/Lmo9ntqy/) is a fiddle of the desired behavior using jQuery. And here is the code:

```js
$(window).resize(function () {
    $(".content").height($(".container").height() / 5);
    $(".content").width($(".container").width() / 5);
    if ($(".content").width() / $(".content").height() < 3) {
        $(".content").height($(".content").width() / 3);
    }
    else {
        $(".content").width($(".content").height() * 3);
    }
    $(".content").css("left", ($(".container").width() - $(".content").width()) / 2);
}).resize();
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%; 
} 
.container {
 position: relative;
  left: 10%;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  top: 10%;
  background-color: maroon;
}
.content {
  background-color: yellow;
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="content"> 
        
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can play with media queries and viewport dimentions. Something like:

```
// I used 15vw just as an example, you should do some maths and find the correct ratio/breakpoint
// this makes the box react to the horizontal resize
@media (min-width: 15vw) { 
  .content {
    height: 12vw;
    width: 28vw;
  }
}

// now, at that breakpoint, the box size depends on the viewport's height
@media (max-height: 15vw) {
  .content {
    height: 80vh;
    width: 185vh;
  }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/f76p5nsr/

Personally, I would try to use vh and vw for all the dimentions of those blocks, this will help you do the math too.

Comment: Unfortunately resizing vertically still doesn't work. I need to set the height of the yellow div to a percentage of the container's height.

Comment: @yazanpro, have you tried my fiddle? I can see the yellow box resizing, maybe I didn't understand what you need

Comment: The height of the yellow should be a fixed percentage of the height of the maroon, while keeping the aspect ratio.

Comment: On my fiddle, the height of the yellow box has a height equals to the brown container on that range of dimentions, just change the height: 80vh to 40vh if you want the yellow box to be 50% of it's parent for example

Comment: The space between the upper edge of the yellow and the upper edge of the maroon should always be, say 80% of the height of the maroon. So in order to keep the aspect ratio, the yellow should shrink in order to keep the 80%

Comment: I've chenged the values to make te yellow box be at most 80% of the parent (the parent is 80vh (80% of the height) and the content is 72vh (80% of 80vh). But the idea is the same as before, you need to play with the values on the media queries and the width/height of the box on each range, but I can see it resizing on both directions, check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/f76p5nsr/1/